# Black bars on left & right in iphone simulator in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am running my app on iphone 5 simulator. But screen is black on both left & right side. I  have placed launch images & app icon but still not working. My app always run in landscape mode. Please tell the solution.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to use `android` tag?

Comment: The black bars are definitely the lack of a correct launch images for 4" devices. Make sure you have a launch images with the size 750 × 1334 pixels.

Comment: I have used 640 *1136

Comment: @TechGuy Sorry you are right the 750 x 1334 is for the 4.7" device, you need 640 × 1136 for 4" devices. You are seeing the bar's because your app is not using the correct launch screens. Are you using image catalog, did you add the new launch screen to the list of launch screens?

Comment: It worked like magic.Please answer it so that i can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black bars are definitely the lack of a correct launch images for 4", 4.7" & 5.5" devices. Make sure you have a launch images with the size

- 4" = 640 × 1136 pixels.
- 4.7" = 750 × 1334 pixels.
- 5" = 1242 × 2208 pixels.

Make sure that add the new launch screen to the list of launch screens or set them in the image catalog.